# JSON format not right

Tags: python, json

I have a highscore that as the structure like this:

```
[(300, 'Test'), (400, 'Test1'), (500, 'Test2'), (500, 'Test2'), (600, 'Test2'), (5, 'Test2'), (500, 'Test2'), (600, 'Test2'), (300, 'Test2'), (100, 'Test2')]
```

and I need to get the JSON format for it like this :

```json
{"Test":300, "Test1":400.....}
```

But how hard I try I only get results like this :

```
[["Test":300],["Test1":400],....]
```

How can I get the json format right? I am using json.dumps(highscore) also tried `son.dumps({highscore})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the list of tuples to a dictionary first before passing it to `json.dumps()`.

```
import json

a = [(300, 'Test'), (400, 'Test1'), (500, 'Test2'), (500, 'Test2'), (600, 'Test2'), (5, 'Test2'), (500, 'Test2'), (600, 'Test2'), (300, 'Test2'), (100, 'Test2')]

rs = json.dumps(dict(a))

print(rs)
>>>{"300": "Test2", "400": "Test1", "500": "Test2", "600": "Test2", "5": "Test2", "100": "Test2"}
```

**Edit**:

If you want to swap the keys and values in the json object you can just swap the tuple positions first but then you would only be able to keep a single instance of each key-value pair as a dictionary can only keep unique keys.

```
a = [(300, 'Test'), (400, 'Test1'), (500, 'Test2'), (500, 'Test2'), (600, 'Test2'), (5, 'Test2'), (500, 'Test2'), (600, 'Test2'), (300, 'Test2'), (100, 'Test2')]

swap = [(y,x) for x,y in a]

res = json.dumps(dict(swap))

print(res)
>>>{"Test": 300, "Test1": 400, "Test2": 100}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you try to use JSON.parse()?

JSON.parse(json);

check this code, may be solved your problem.